# TrueCrypt to protect Windows server and web application

Tags: security, encryption, truecrypt, web-applications

As an additional layer of security on a windows server (stored on-site) I am
considering to use TrueCrypt.

However my concern is if my webapp will still work as expected? I dont want anyone
to access the machine but still have the webapp working as normal over the LAN.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for any large-scale application that has to deal with high load, this would be a bad idea, but if it's small, this is a fine solution to encryption your data and running your web app off the mounted TrueCrypt drive.

Comment: the app itself will be used in a small office with 4 client PCs.its not large scale. Would encrypting the C drive or partition on the server still allow the webapp to be hosted over the LAN/data to be read/written to the database on the server etc?

Comment: Yes, TrueCrypt makes this seamless.

Answer (score 0):

The the way TrueCrypt and similar full disk encryption applications work hides the encryption layer from the operating system/applications etc. There is a slight performance hit, as every disk access requires an encrypt or decrypt, but for a low load application it will just work.

The slight caveat would be around unattended reboots - I am guessing you only use this server when you are on site, but if you needed to use it remotely, and a power cut had caused it to power down, you would need a physical presence to get it started up again.

Comment: the server will be used when i am offsite. so that may be an issue if im not around and the box shuts down unexpectedly. Could I, encrypt a partition or even folder and give access to a user to start stop the services?

Comment: @Santiago - if you are just encrypting a partition or folder, then yes, you will be able to do that. Not quite as secure as full disk encryption, but more practical in this set of circumstances.